# NSXML Parser returns blank Results

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, httprequest, nsxmlparser

I'm currently developing an iOS App (target=iPod touch) for displaying some information, which are based in a PostgreSQL database and I'm a very beginner. I did a lot of research, but I found nothing, which really helped for fixing my problem.

At the moment I get my data from a php file, which is the "bridge" between the iOS App and the database. For that purpose I use a http-request for asking the php file for data in xml format. Inside the php file I use

```
SELECT query_to_xml('".$queryString."', false, true, '') as xml
```

to get a xml file in return.

So far everything works fine, so that I have a string variable with the xml result from the query available in my iOS App.

**This is what I get:**

```
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <id>4</id>
  <invnr>61821B741AEBI8</invnr>
  <art>c</art>
  <type_id>2</type_id>
  <rechnung></rechnung>
  <standort>G01E01R01</standort>
  <erstellt>2011-12-06</erstellt>
  <gekauft>2003-01-01</gekauft>
</row>
```

In objective-c I would like to have two arrays:

**caption array**

The first array should hold the captions from the xml file (id, invnr, art, type_id, rechnung, standort, erstellt, gekauft). The entry "row" should not be inside the array.

**value array**

The second array should only save the values- also the empty ones. In that example it would be 4, 61821B741AEBI8, c, 2, , G01E01R01, 2011-12-06, 2003-01-01

**Using the NSXML Parser**

This is the config, which I use currently for parsing the xml and for saving the data into the arrays.

**Parser didStartElement**

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                      qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
                                      attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    element = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    if(!dataCaptions){
      dataCaptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"id"] ||
     [elementName isEqualToString:@"invnr"] ||
     [elementName isEqualToString:@"art"] ||
     [elementName isEqualToString:@"type_id"] ||
     [elementName isEqualToString:@"rechnung"] ||
     [elementName   isEqualToString:@"standort"] ||
     [elementName isEqualToString:@"erstellt"] ||
     [elementName isEqualToString:@"gekauft"]){

    [element setString:elementName];
    [dataCaptions addObject:elementName];
    }
}
```

**Parser foundCharacters**

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if(!dataValues){
      dataValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    BOOL copy;

    if([element isEqualToString:@"id"] ||
       [element isEqualToString:@"invnr"] ||
       [element isEqualToString:@"art"] ||
       [element isEqualToString:@"type_id"] ||
       [element isEqualToString:@"rechnung"]||
       [element isEqualToString:@"standort"] ||
       [element isEqualToString:@"erstellt"] ||
       [element isEqualToString:@"gekauft"]){

       copy = YES;

    }else{
       copy = NO;
    }

    if(copy){
      [dataValues addObject:string];
      NSLog(@"Found: %@ with value: %@", element, string);

    }
}
```

**Parser didEndElement**

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

}
```

**Output and Problem**

The problem is that the parser seems to go several times through an element. That causes that my value array seems like that:

```
 2013-03-14 12:54:54.591 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Array Values(
    4,
    "\n  ",
    61821B741AEBI8,
    "\n  ",
    c,
    "\n  ",
    2,
    "\n  ",
    "\n  ",
    G01E01R01,
    "\n  ",
    "2011-12-06",
    "\n  ",
    "2003-01-01",
    "\n"
)
```

The output is also a bit complicated. Is my though wrong that the parser first take the starting xml-tag eg. (Parser didStartElement)  ,than reads in the values 4 (Parser foundCharacters) and at least reads  (Parser didEndElement) ?

I hope there is somebody who could help to solve that issue.
Thanks and best greetings- Tobias

```
2013-03-14 12:54:54.423 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: id with value: 4
2013-03-14 12:54:54.425 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: id with value: 

2013-03-14 12:54:54.426 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: invnr with value: 61821B741AEBI8
2013-03-14 12:54:54.428 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: invnr with value: 

2013-03-14 12:54:54.430 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: art with value: c
2013-03-14 12:54:54.432 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: art with value: 

2013-03-14 12:54:54.444 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: type_id with value: 2
2013-03-14 12:54:54.446 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: type_id with value: 

2013-03-14 12:54:54.448 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: rechnung with value: 

2013-03-14 12:54:54.450 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: standort with value: G01E01R01
2013-03-14 12:54:54.451 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: standort with value: 

2013-03-14 12:54:54.454 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: erstellt with value: 2011-12-06
2013-03-14 12:54:54.456 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: erstellt with value: 

2013-03-14 12:54:54.461 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: gekauft with value: 2003-01-01
2013-03-14 12:54:54.464 BarcodeScanner[582:907] Found: gekauft with value:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that you need to implement `didStartElement`, `foundCharacters` and `didEndElement`. You're also correct that `foundCharacters` will be called several times in the course of processing a given element, so you need to handle this by *appending* the characters to a string, rather than creating a new standalone string every time. Or, as Apple puts it in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> The parser object may send the delegate several
>   parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an
>   element. Because string may be only part of the total character
>   content for the current element, you should append it to the current
>   accumulation of characters until the element changes.

As an example, here's my complete implementation of a simple working parser from my current project. Note how simple `foundCharacters` is - all you need to do at the basic level is keep appending the characters to a string until `didEndElement` is called (then you can clear it within `didEndElement` and start the appending process again):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"device"]){
        self.currentDeviceID = [[SRDeviceID alloc]init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"deviceList"]){
        [self.pairingTableView reloadData];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"device"]){
        [self.deviceIDListFromServer addObject:self.currentDeviceID];
    }

    //The accumulation of characters for the current element is complete,
    //so we can tidy up the string and use the result:
    NSString* finalParsedString = [self.currentParseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"deviceName"]){
        self.currentDeviceID.deviceName = finalParsedString;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"UUID"]){
        self.currentDeviceID.uuid = finalParsedString;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"deviceLocation"]){
        self.currentDeviceID.location = finalParsedString;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"deviceLastSeenTime"]){
        self.currentDeviceID.lastSeenTime = finalParsedString;
    }

    //Now we've used the accumulated string from the current element,
    //we can clear it ready to start the accumulation process for
    //the next element's contents:
    self.currentParseString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //All we need to do here is add the next lot of characters
    //to the accumulating string for the current element,
    //which continues to happen until didEndElement is called:
    [self.currentParseString appendString:string];
}
```